# How to remove Byte Order Mark from linked CSV file in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a CSV file.  I linked it with access using DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim,....

It works fine.

However, in the linked view, the first column contains the BOM, so it shows up like ï»¿Column1.

Is there a way to remove this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link out.  Not sure if it will work for you but might get you in the correct direction  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e8c18df7-2b8a-45b0-a51c-9fe60079a081/importing-a-csv-file-in-utf8-format

Comment: Does it help if you supply the `CodePage` value `msoEncodingUTF8` (value 65001) as the very last argument to the `.TransferText` method?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the CodePage method without success.

I did find some ideas of removing the BOM before linking though. [Here's one of them.](http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2013/05/what-if-import-file-txtcsv-having-bom.html)